# A MultiJson::DecodeError occurred

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a Rails 3.2.11 app in which users can register for the site. This has been working flawlessly for a couple of months now. But within the past 24 hours, I've encountered the following error messages in the logs.

The exact error is as follows:

```
A MultiJson::DecodeError occurred in registrations#create:

795: unexpected token at ''
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
```

Every other piece of help I've found has shown that the "unexpected token" is some ill-formatted string, but my error doesn't give any hint as to what is going wrong.  Like I said, this hasn't been a problem until just recently, and I've pushed no new code in the past week.  Any ideas as to why this error is now occurring?

```
------------------------------- Request:

* URL       : https://domain.com/users
* IP address: x.x.x.x
* Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"veY+0DHEr8omNuW95bTxxxxxxNvUCPIPOvw1MUSCDhw=", "user"=>{"user_type"=>"student", "email"=>"email@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "privacy_question_id"=>"1", "privacy_answer"=>"answer"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"devise/registrations"}
* Rails root: /app
```

Thanks for the help!

Rails 3.2.11,
Ruby 1.9.3